# pip gets "read timed out" by unusual reason

Tags: command-line, networking, python, pip

Command `pip install future` returns:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/future/
```

Five times, and then `No matching distribution found`.

I have tried:

1. this command with flag `--default-timeout=1000` (and 100, of course) doesn't help. It doesn't relate to the throughput of my Internet connection.
2. check connection using `nmap -p 443 pypi.org` at the same time returns a valid latency:

   ```
    Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-17 22:02 IST
    Nmap scan report for pypi.org (151.101.128.223)
    Host is up (0.067s latency).
    Other addresses for pypi.org (not scanned): ...        
    PORT    STATE SERVICE
    443/tcp open  https        
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.43 seconds
   ```
3. run command with `sudo` -- same result, of course, but my setup allowed to install without `sudo`.
4. I tried to check it by wireshark. I see several lines, each of them with [RST] - reset, connection termination.

   Example line:

   ```
    7807    476.831742090   2a00:...:a9e3   2a04:4e42:400::223  TCP 76  36918 → 443 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
   ```

And I have no idea why was it reset.

5. It works from another computer from the same network.

Can you suggest any way how can I resolve my issue, and be able to use pip?
The installation process have to be automated, to I can't resolve it by manually download of sources & install them.

Comment: I know that it maybe not very helpful, but have to share...
I'm on windows but having the exact same issue. This question is the most accurate description of what I see (after hours of internet search). Can access pypi.org from browsers without any issue. Mac on the same network has no issues.
Tried --default-timeout=1000
Also tried adding: --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org

nothing helps. hope you will get a useful answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually hard-reset of the router did help.

I'm not sure what was the exact reason, but I guess it somehow related to the fact, that modern servers in Cloud change their IP-addresses relatively quickly, and DNS servers sometimes don't renew themselves fast enough.
Somehow some of paths to pypi.org was corrupted, and some didn't. Which lead to fact that second computer could reach it, from browser or `curl` it was possible to reach it, but `pip` failed to reach pypi.org.